# Recursive output to Fremarkers

Tags: html, spring-boot, recursion, freemarker

I'm trying to make the display of messages on the site from the table recursive ... Now, as seen in the screenshot works, but in the template, a hardcore that displays a maximum of 2 attachments, tell me how to write the correct recursion, to display as many attachments and not hardcore as .

[example of how it works now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uihR.png)

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVONf.png)

template.ftl

```
<#list comment as msg>
<#if !msg.reply??>
    <li>
        ${msg.message}
        <ul>
            <li>
        <#list replyes as reply>
            <#if reply.reply.toString() == msg.toString()>
                ${reply.message}
                <#list replyes as sub_reply>
                    <#if sub_reply.reply.toString() == reply.toString()>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                ${sub_reply.message}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </#if>
                </#list>
            </#if>
          </#list>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </#if>
</#list>
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "chat")
public String charPage(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
                   Map<String, Object> model) {
model.put("comment",commentRepo.findAllByMessageIsNotNullOrderById());
model.put("replyes",commentRepo.findAllByReplyIsNotNull());

return "chatmessage";
}
```

Repo:

```
public interface CommentRepo extends JpaRepository <Comment, Long> {
   List<Comment> findAllByMessageIsNotNullOrderById();
   List<Comment> findAllByReplyIsNotNull();
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Comment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private String message;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "comment_id")
private Comment reply;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;


public Comment() {
}
.....
```

I tried to write a macro, but the page falls.
macro:

```
<#list comment as msg>
<#if !msg.reply??>
    <li>
        ${msg.message}
        <ul>
            <li>
                <@treeView msg, replyes/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</#if>
</#list>

<#macro treeView msg listReply>
  <#list listReply as reply>
    <#if reply.reply.toString() == msg.toString>
    ${reply.message}
    <@ treeView reply, replyes/>
    </#if>
  </#list>
</#macro>
```

Tell me how to write the correct macro or method in Freemarkers

Comment: The algorithm itself (which is not specific to FreeMarker) seems to contain oversights. For example, the `treeView` macro can't be good as it nowhere prints `<ul>` and `<li>`. Work those out, and if there are still FreeMarker errors, then copy-parse the error message, don't just say that it doesn't work. (BTW, at the moment you miss a `()` after `msg.toString`. Anyway, the `.toString()` can certainly be omitted, or if not, writing `?string` is more standard.)

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a well-functioning macro for searching in the recursive records table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOkVy.png)

```
   <#list comment as msg>
    <#if !msg.reply??>
        <li>
            ${msg.message}
                <@treeView msg replyes/>
        </li>
    </#if>
</#list>

<#macro treeView msg listReply>
<#list listReply as reply>
    <#if reply.reply.toString() == msg.toString()>
    <ul>
        <li>
            ${reply.message}
                <@treeView reply replyes/>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </#if>
</#list>
</#macro>
```